# Аугментация на лету с генерацией дополнительных изображений (очень маленький датасет)

Tags: python

Имеется маленький датасет для обучения НС (около 100 изображений). Создаю аугментацию изображений

```
*train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,          
                             brightness_range = [0.2, 0.6],    
                             preprocessing_function=add_noise) 
train_generator.fit(train_X)*
```

при попытке обучить НС выдается ошибку "На вашем вводе закончились данные; прерывание обучения. Убедитесь, что ваш набор данных или генератор могут генерировать по крайней мере пакеты "steps_per_epoch * epochs" (в данном случае 900 пакетов). Возможно, вам потребуется использовать функцию repeat() при создании вашего набора данных."

```
*modelAutocodText.fit(train_generator.flow(x_train, y_train,
                                          batch_size = 16,
                                          shuffle=False),
                                  steps_per_epoch = 9, 
                                  epochs = 100, 
                                  validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
                                  verbose=1)*

*WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 900 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.*
```

Пыталась использовать рекомендованную функцию repeat(). Но, опять ошибки.

```
*import itertools 

modelAutocodText.fit(train_generator.flow(itertools.repeat(x_train,times=900),
    
                                              itertools.repeat(y_train,times=900),
                                              batch_size = 16,
                                              shuffle=False),
                                      steps_per_epoch = 9, 
                                      epochs = 100, 
                                      validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
                                      verbose=1)*
 *TypeError: object of type 'itertools.repeat' has no len()*
```

Из тех комментариев, которые я читала ранее, я так и не поняла как это исправить.

Нужно из размерности x_train (120, 240, 520, 1) сделать (900, 240, 520, 1) для подачи в нейронную сеть на обучение

Comment: Попробуйте сделать список, у списка есть длина: `list(itertools.repeat(x_train,times=900))` и `list(itertools.repeat(y_train,times=900))`

Comment: 1) print(len(list(itertools.repeat(x_train,times=900))), len(list(itertools.repeat(y_train,times=900)))) 
-> 900 900
если смотреть размер самого x_train, то 
2) print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
-> (120, 240, 520, 1)

Comment: Я не знаю, что вы хотите сказать или спросить, я вам подсказал, что можно попытаться победить ошибку `TypeError: object of type 'itertools.repeat' has no len()` сделав `list` из `itertools.repeat`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Мне нужно из размерности x_train (120, 240, 520, 1) сделать (900, 240, 520, 1), чтобы подавать на обучение в нейронку